# Server Rendering SyntaxError with React/Redux/Express

Tags: express, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get my app rendering from the server and so was trying to implement the ServerRendering example from here: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

I can successfully run server.js but I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error @ bundle.js:2 once I load up localhost. I believe it has to do with the renderFullPage() function:

```
function renderFullPage(html, initialState) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}
        </script>
        <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
}
```

If I remove the line `<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>` the error goes away, but then the counter doesn't work.

Here is the bundle.js that the error references:

[bundle.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHTCn.png)

It should be referencing bundle.js in my dist folder but it's not for some reason? If I make an index.html file exactly the same as what renderFullPage is returning, except getting rid of `${html}` and 
`<script>
   window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}
</script>`

then the counter works fine. When I do the server side rendering it seems like the client can't find the bundle.js code so creates one that has the exact same code as what it received from the server, and so there is an error as it runs into html when it's expecting javascript.

Comment: "If I remove the line the error goes away, but then the counter doesn't work."  Which line are you talking about?

Comment: <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>, I think the problem is the client isn't picking up the /dist/bundle.js file which is the file my webpack outputs to.

Comment: huh... that wasn't showing up for me before... sorry

Comment: Ya forgot it when I first submitted, put it in after.

Comment: `I can successfully run server.js` I disagree, you may be able to listen on a port, but once you engage server.js for a request it's falling flat. Are you writing ES6 or ES5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `bundle.js` contains HTML rather than your client-side scripts. Are you using a catch-all route and not letting it load your static assets? Your `express.static` middleware `use` call should go before this bit of code (middleware order matters).